# Add Javascript file to login in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento, authentication, module, magento2

At the moment I'm writing a custom module to enable 2FA on a Magento 2 webshop. To do this successfully I have to add a Javascript file to the existing login view. When clicking the login button a function from this file has to execute.

Things I have tried so far:

- Adding the Javascript file to requirejs-config.js
- Overriding the block file.

Both options didn't do the thing for me.

Anyone who can help?